# How do I get a normalized database with Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a model with sequelize that exhibits some normalization. This is my first experience with sequelize and I *think* I can get it to do what I want but I'm struggling.

Here are my two tables.

```
dbo.Users
| id | firstName | lastName       | roleId | createdAt.. | updatedAt.. |
|  1 | john      | doe            |      1 |
|  2 | chris     | christopherson |      1 |
|  3 | joe       | montana        |      2 |
```

```
dbo.Roles
| id | roleName   | createdAt.. | updatedAt.. |
|  1 | admin      |
|  2 | power-user |
```

Basically what I'm looking for is that once I've created my models correctly, when I insert/create a "user" with `Role: admin` it (sequelize) know's there's an `admin` record already inside `dbo.Roles` so it grabs the corresponding `role.id` (1) and inserts that into the new user record.

Now if I create a new user with `Role: user`, because it's not already in `dbo.Roles`, it'll create a third record

```
dbo.Roles
| id | roleName   | createdAt.. | updatedAt.. |
|  1 | admin      |
|  2 | power-user |
|  3 | user       |
```

inside `dbo.Roles` and add

```
dbo.Users
| id | firstName | lastName       | roleId | createdAt.. | updatedAt.. |
|  1 | john      | doe            |      1 |
|  2 | chris     | christopherson |      1 |
|  3 | joe       | montana        |      2 |
|  4 | jeff      | bezos          |      3 |
```

to my `dbo.Users` table.

This is what I've tried so far but I keep getting `SequelizeEagerLoadingError`s or I get duplicate `admin` records in my `dbo.Roles` table.

```js
const Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
  RoleName: Sequelize.STRING,
  CreatedBy: Sequelize.STRING
});

const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  FirstName: Sequelize.STRING,
  LastName: Sequelize.STRING,
  UserPrincipalName: Sequelize.STRING,
  Department: Sequelize.STRING,
  CreatedBy: Sequelize.STRING,
  UpdatedBy: Sequelize.STRING,
  RoleId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: Role,
      key: 'id'
    }
  }
});

Role.hasMany(User, { foreignKey: 'RoleId' });
```

Calling a `User.create`:

```
await User.create({
  FirstName: 'Jeff',
  LastName: 'Bezos'
  Role: {
    RoleName: 'admin',
    CreatedBy: 'jimjones@gmail.com'
  }
}, {
  include: [{
    model: Role
  }]
});
```

Comment: Hi, could you please post the code where you insert the user as well? It might be possible that the issue is there.

Comment: So here's the `create`/`insert` call. What I'm seeing is if I call that `.create()` twice both with 'admin' roles it creates two records in my `Roles` table.

Comment: My suspicion is that you need to use the ID rather than the name, because the name is not a unique field. Could you try referring to the Role by the ID instead of the name to see if that works?

Comment: Well, that's the thing. Should I make the `roleName` unique?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt, I'm not 100% sure that would solve the problem but it's worth a try first.

Comment: I simply get a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error`